# Why am I getting a wrong binary pattern?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a function to print the Binary Representation of an integer which is 4-Bytes on my machine. 
I'm creating a `mask = 0x80000000`  which should be 
`( 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 )`

and creating a loop to shift this mask right and making `and` operation and if it is one I'll print 1 else I'll print 0, but I'm getting wrong results!

For example: for decimal 10 I'm getting `00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void Binary( int ) ;
int main()
{
    Binary(10) ; // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111
    while(1);
    return 0;
}

void Binary( int num )
{
    int mask = 0x80000000 ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<32; i++)
    {
        if( (mask>>i)&num )
        {
            printf("1") ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0") ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `0x80000000` is out of `int` range. You might want to use `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: in hexadecimal it isn't true that each digit is represented in 4-Bits ? ! 
so , for 4Bytes int . 4Bytes*8Bits so 0x80000000 is represented in 4Bytes ?

Comment: The value of `0x80000000` is a positive number which is larger than any positive number represantable by `int`.

Comment: I would change the type to `uint32_t` (from `stdint.h`) since you are assuming 32 bits anyway. (Or, alternatively, create the mask from the number of bits instead of hard-coding the mask for 32.)

Comment: Always use unsigned for bit twiddling

Answer (score 1):

When you shift the int right, it fills with the sign bit because it is signed.  So 0x80000000 >> 1 is 0xc0000000; >> 2 is 0xe0000000; >> 23 is 0xffffffff; >> 31 is 0xffffffff.

The value 10 is binary 1010, so it and to non-zero for every i in 28,29,30,31.
You can test this by modifying your program to try some different numbers:

```
4: 00000000000000000000000000000111
8: 00000000000000000000000000000111
15:00000000000000000000000000001111
16:00000000000000000000000000011111
```

As the comments mention, if you switch to unsigned, this will not happen.

ps:
It is entirely possible that signed shifting has been redefined to be undefined behaviour, in which case you are lucky your house didn’t burn down.

Comment: Both right-shifting signed values and out of range conversion from unsigned to signed values is implementation defined, not undefined.